# Bug on line 52 of my javascript code and i can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using the below javascript code in my appery.io app.  I keep getting an error which states the following:

```
6/25/2014 9:37:35 PM:   Script All_Users_Data: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined ( @ 52 : 33 ) -> if (all_photo[i].the_user._id == id) {
```

Please help me identify the bug.  I'm attempting to pull data from 3 collections, sync them up by _id from a 'users' collection and then output user profile type information.

```
var all_users = eval(DatabaseUser.query('52895ecce4b056c5e94f34f9'));
var all_profiles = eval(Collection.query('52895ecce4b056c5e94f34f9', 'profile'));
var all_status = eval(Collection.query('52895ecce4b056c5e94f34f9', 'Status'));
var all_photo = eval(Collection.query('52895ecce4b056c5e94f34f9', 'photo'));

// loop on all users
for (var i=0;i<all_users.length;i++)
{
    // call function to search for user profile and then add first name to current user            item
    getProfile(all_users[i]._id, all_users[i]);
    // call function to search for user status and then add last status to current user   item  
    getstatus(all_users[i]._id, all_users[i]);
    getphoto(all_users[i]._id, all_users[i]);
}

// function get user item and user id and find user profile by its id and update it
function getProfile(id,curUser)
{
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < all_profiles.length; i++) {
        // if cur user id = profile id assign profile name to the user
        if (all_profiles[i].the_user._id == id)
        {
            curUser.firstName = all_profiles[i].firstName;
            curUser.university = all_profiles[i].university ;

            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        curUser.f_name = "";
    }
}

// function get user item and user id and find user status by its id and update it
function getstatus(id, curUser) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < all_status.length; i++) {
        if (all_status[i].the_user._id == id) {
            curUser.status = all_status[i].status;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        curUser.status = "";
    }
}
function getphoto(id, curUser) {
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < all_photo.length; i++) {
        if (all_photo[i].the_user._id == id) {
            curUser.photo = all_photo[i].photo;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        curUser.photo = "";
    }
}

// return full user data updated wih status and first name
response.success(JSON.stringify(all_users), "application/json");
```

Comment: Seems like the the_user object in all_profiles is null. Try verifying the result in console by logging it like :
console.log(all_profiles[i]);

Comment: Before accessing the elements of your objects, you should check that they are defined.

Comment: `eval()` - wait, what? That's most likely the first 4 bugs in this code.

Comment: sidenote - `break`ing out of these for loops once you've found something would be a nice improvement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means this is undefined:

```
all_photo[i].the_user
```

So as it is undefined, it most definitely doesn't have the property `_id`, as undefined objects have no properties, because they are undefined.

Does that define the source of the problem?

--

Use your browser console - it helps:

```
console.log(all_photo);
```

Then you can check out what is happening with that object and what properties it does have after you `eval` it.

Comment: Thanks much for your help, that helps a bit.  I see where the lords closed the ticket but i still don't have a clear understanding why.  However I guess the power resides with them  :)